# What do these Chinese symbols mean?

Tags: character-identification

Looking for age or value of this bowl found while cleaning family home.

[image]

This is the inside of the bowl.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZZvq.jpg[image]

Comment: How about put your camera right above the bowl?

Comment: This is inside of bowl

Answer (score 1):

the characters are:

碧 - [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=碧](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%A2%A7)

王 - [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=王](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%8E%8B)

玲 - [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=玲](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%8E%B2)

玩 - [http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=玩](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%8E%A9)

very likely, it's an antique. try to contact sotheby, or christie :)

Answer (score 1):

Your photo is not clear enough.

I think there is an 珑 (not 玩）, 玲珑 is a word.

珑 is simplified Chinese. So this is made after 1950s.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:

After more observation,  it looks more like 碧王珍玩 (碧玉珍玩) to me

[珍玩](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%8F%8D%E7%8E%A9) (珍贵的供玩赏的东西 - precious things to enjoy)

- 碧玉珍玩 (jasper like treasure)
- If it is 碧王珍玩 , then 碧王 (king of blue green) is likely a brand name

~~~~

It make more sense to replace 王 with 玉

The whole thing would be 碧玉玲珑 (exquisite as jasper)

> [玲瓏](http://www.zdic.net/c/2/110/297414.htm) : *exquisite (精巧细微)*
>
> [碧玉](http://www.zdic.net/c/7/97/170267.htm) : *jasper; (一种不透明隐晶质石英)*

These two terms can be found in idioms:

> [八面玲瓏](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/21509/) (be smooth and slick (in establishing social relations), [小家碧玉](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AE%B6%E7%A2%A7%E7%8E%89) (in old times, refers to a beautiful young woman in a modestly wealthy family)

Some of the paint might had been scraped off. (the tiny dot in 玉 and the up-angled stoke in 珑)

As Bob Johnson stated, it is a modern era product, (post 1950)

Comment: Just so amazed you can guess 玲珑碧玉 out of this , the character shape is so strange

Comment: @神秘德里克 碧王珍玩 is my final answer

Answer (score 0):

It's 碧玉玲珑(碧玉玲瓏). Then I guess it was made around 1980, because these overly simplified characters look like 二简字. In that period of time, 二简字(The second set of simplified characters) was promoted over the country. Not long after it was abandoned.
I must point out that, several decades ago, China was a low-literacy country, and characters were chosen or written in such a casual way by common people. They used 繁体、一简、二简 randomly, and often simplified characters in their own ways.
[image]
So maybe this is the case.